# Turn off Temporary Viewer Node?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I've just discovered the Temporary Viewer Node in Blender by clicking Shift-Ctrl-LMB on a node. Very useful! Question: Is there a way to turn off the Temporary Viewer Node just as quickly without having to delete the Viewer Node and reconnect the BSDF to the Material Output? Thanks. Blender 3.1.2

Comment: You have your answer below, but that's actually one of the functions of the Node Wrangler addon which has many other useful functions. There's a quick YT tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvfQ1pMxgDk) and you can find the full hotkey list for it if you open the dropdown description panel for the Node Wrangler addon on the Edit > Preferences > Addons tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just click Shift>Ctrl>LMB on the principled BSDF. It will automatically remove the viewer node and connect the P BSDF.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Much appreciated. I looked at the Blender 3 online manual, but it only explained how to add the viewer node, so that's why I pinged the brain trust here. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! Just keep experimenting with stuff along the way !)

Comment: This doesn't work if you're inside of a group, because that still will keep the new route out of the group it created in the first place. So to fix it you would need to go out of all the groups and sub-groups and click the original group with shift ctrl lmb, which is far from being useful.